# How to monitor for newly created Azure Subscriptions?

Tags: azure, events, azure-eventgrid, azure-subscription

I want to monitor for newly created Azure Subscriptions. Ideally, I would like to subscribe to events at the management group level and ingest them on event grid. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

On my research there is no native way for event grid to subscribe to events on the Management Group or Tenant Level.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, there is no native way to add an event grid at [management group level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#understand-scope).

However, you can use a polling technique (Azure TimerTrigger Function) with a [REST GET request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list?tabs=HTTP) to obtain a list of all subscriptions, comparing to previously state and publishing its diference to the AEG custom topic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering if there is a more real-time way of doing it? Like if there is a way of generating a custom event at the MG level?